# How to alignments string to the right

Tags: java

So i have this simple string:

```
dgj gjnw - gwgt: 434.572
jfdhdr - Report: 342.203
dsdgs ryr4y4: 26.724
etet erte neytwe eyqw: 1338.843
etyer eyey: 16.742
efaewf were: 122.325
```

I want to order this like a table and alignments the `values` in normal order for example:

```
dgj gjnw - gwgt:        434.572
jfdhdr - Report:        342.203
dsdgs ryr4y4:           26.724
etet erte neytwe eyqw:  1338.843
etyer eyey:             16.742
efaewf were:            122.325
```

Comment: is it a single string or multiple strings or a array??

Comment: Use tab `\t` after each `:`

Comment: Seems like you should start by splitting on newlines. Then split on colons, then figure out the maximum size of the first column (how many characters before the colon). Then you can start constructing your output. Maybe you can share your code so far and tell us where you got stuck?

Comment: this is from List and i print it via loop

Comment: Please have a look at Java [Formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can give space (`\t`) after occurrence of `:` character. Try the following code.

```
String s = "dgj gjnw - gwgt: 434.572";
    String s0=" ";
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
        if(s.charAt(i) == ':'){
            s0 = s.substring(i+1);
            break;
        }
    }   
    System.out.println("\t"+s0);
```

I've taken the characters after `:` as another substring and printed after giving `\t` at last.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution which has been tested on IntelliJ and appears to be working.  First I iterate over each line to find the length of the longest string, which value will determine how much whitespace padding needs to be added to each line in the output.  Next I iterate as second time, applying the appropriate amount of padding.  In the second iteration I split by colon to separate the labels from values.

```
String lineInput= "dgj gjnw - gwgt: 434.572\n" +
                  "jfdhdr - Report: 342.203\n" +
                  "dsdgs ryr4y4: 26.724\n" +
                  "etet erte neytwe eyqw: 1338.843\n" +
                  "etyer eyey: 16.742\n" +
                  "efaewf were: 122.325\n";

String[] lines = lineInput.split("\n");
int maxLength = 0;

// find length of longest line
for (String line : lines) {
    int length = line.replaceAll("\\s\\d+\\.\\d+", "").length();
    if (length > maxLength) {
        maxLength = length;
    }
}

// reformat each line and output to console
for (String line : lines) {
    int length = line.replaceAll("\\s\\d+\\.\\d+", "").length();
    String padding = new String(new char[maxLength-length]).replace("\0", " ");
    String[] parts = line.split(":");
    String output = parts[0] + ":" + padding + parts[1];
     System.out.println(output);
}
```

**Output:**

```
dgj gjnw - gwgt:       434.572
jfdhdr - Report:       342.203
dsdgs ryr4y4:          26.724
etet erte neytwe eyqw: 1338.843
etyer eyey:            16.742
efaewf were:           122.325
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a[] = { "dgj gjnw - gwgt: 434.572", "jfdhdr - Report: 342.203", "dsdgs ryr4y4: 26.724", "etet erte neytwe eyqw: 1338.843", "etyer eyey: 16.742",
                "efaewf were: 122.325" };
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].split(": ")[0].length() < 15)//checking for length so that the data is perfectly aligned as you wanted.
                System.out.println(a[i].split(":")[0] + ":\t\t" + a[i].split(":")[1]);
            else
                System.out.println(a[i].split(":")[0] + ":\t" + a[i].split(":")[1]);

        }
}
```

the above code produces the following output:

```
dgj gjnw - gwgt:         434.572
jfdhdr - Report:         342.203
dsdgs ryr4y4:            26.724
etet erte neytwe eyqw:   1338.843
etyer eyey:              16.742
efaewf were:             122.325
```

Answer (score 0):

You might start with this snippet.

```
// create a list of the input strings
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("dgj gjnw - gwgt: 434.572",
        "jfdhdr - Report: 342.203",
        "dsdgs ryr4y4: 26.724",
        "etet erte neytwe eyqw: 1338.843",
        "etyer eyey: 16.742",
        "efaewf were: 122.325");
// find the maximum length of the left part (it assume there is no additional
// colon in the left part
int maxColonPos = strings.stream().mapToInt(s->s.indexOf(':')).max().getAsInt();
// construct a output format string
String format = "%-" + maxColonPos + "s: %s%n";
// stream over all strings
strings.stream()
        // split them at the position of the colon (it assume that there are
        // always two colons
        .map((s) -> s.split(":", 2)) 
        // print the splitted values using the output format
        .forEach((p) -> {System.out.printf(format, p[0], p[1]);
});
```

output

```
dgj gjnw - gwgt      :  434.572
jfdhdr - Report      :  342.203
dsdgs ryr4y4         :  26.724
etet erte neytwe eyqw:  1338.843
etyer eyey           :  16.742
efaewf were          :  122.325
```